# Is there a right semihereditary domain which isn't right Ore?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I do not have a lot of examples in my head for semihereditary domains at all, and I haven't been able to see how to resolve this question:

> Is there a right semihereditary domain which isn't right Ore?

Reminders:

- A **right semihereditary ring** is one in which all finitely generated right ideals are projective as modules.
- A **[right Ore domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_domain)** is a domain where the nonzero elements satisfy the Ore conditions. However, if I remember correctly these conditions are equivalent to the domain having finite right uniform dimension.

My "obvious" examples of semihereditary domains are Bezout domains, but those are all Ore!

Comment: Dear @JackSchmidt : Not only non-Noetherian, but infinite right uniform dimension. I'm mystified by the last the last part: *that contains a subring isomorphic to a free algebra over its center.* How do we arrive at that idea?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Ah, great! Thanks for the pointers. Do you know about *free ideal rings*? I have a few vague memories that free algebras in noncommuting determinants are such things, and that they are always Ore (and obviously hereditary.) But I was thinking maybe a slight variation (infinitely many variables perhaps?) might be able to shed the Ore-ness without shedding the semihereditary property. If so, then they're likely to contain such a free algebra in their center...

Comment: @JackSchmidt Maybe: I had thought that they were Ore, but maybe they were given as an example of non-Ore rings embedding into division rings to show the difference the density makes. They are obviously hereditary (and coherent, as all semihereditary rings are.)

Comment: @JackSchmidt I don't have Lam nearby at the moment, so if you can confirm that our free ideal ring isn't Ore, please make it an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Converted comments to a self-contained answer (I didn't include the free algebra implies fir proof, but if I recall, this is just division algorithm). Let me know if you want citations to Lam or Cohn or some other reliable source. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free algebras provide an example:

Let $k$ be a field, and let $R=k\langle x,y\rangle$ be the free associative, unital $k$-algebra in two (non-commuting) indeterminates. Then every left and right ideal of $R$ is free, and so $R$ is necessarily hereditary on both sides. However, the right ideal $X$ generated by $x$ and the right ideal $Y$ generated by $y$ have zero intersection, since the elements of $X$ are precisely the $k$-linear combinations of monomials beginning with $x$ and the elements of $Y$ are precisely the $k$-linear combinations of monomials beginning with $y$; $R$ is a $k$-direct sum $k \oplus X \oplus Y$. If $S=R\setminus\{0\}$, then $xS \cap yR = (X \setminus \{0\}) \cap Y = (X \cap Y) \setminus \{0\} = \{0\} \setminus \{0\} = \varnothing$ so the set of non-zero-divisors of $R$ is not a right permutable set, and $R$ is not a right Ore domain (or a left Ore domain).

Comment: Man, am I glad I brought up free ideal rings... I might not have been reminded for a long time that while they embed in division rings, they aren't Ore. This example is a lot simpler than what I thought would be necessary. Thanks!